# Sending POST request with C++ to Apache Webserver

Tags: php, c++, apache

I'm trying to send some data from a c++ application to the apache server on the same machine.
I wrote some c++ code to send a POST request to the apache server.
The PHP script on the index.php page should collect the data and output them on the web page.

My C++ code:

```
      void send_post()
       {
        portno = 80;
        sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (sockfd < 0)
        {
            cout << "ERROR opening socket" << endl;
        }
        else {cout << "Socket opened -> ";}

        server = gethostbyname("localhost");
        if (server == NULL)
        {
            cout << "ERROR, no such host" << endl;
            exit(0);
        }
        bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char*)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_length);
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

        if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        {
        cout << "ERROR connecting" << endl;
        }
        else {cout << "Connected -> ";}
        bzero(upcbuffer,512);
        sprintf(upcbuffer, "%s", post_req.c_str());
        z = write(sockfd,upcbuffer,strlen(upcbuffer));
        if (z < 0)
        {
        cout << "ERROR writing to socket";
        }
        else {cout << "Wrote successfully to socket" << endl;}
        close(sockfd);
        cout << "Socket closed now" << endl;
        }
```

With my post_req string:

```
post_req = "POST /index.php HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Length: 8\r\n\r\ntesttest\r\n";
```

My PHP code on index.php

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Sadly I can't see anything on the index page.
I'm sure that the POST request is well formatted.
Could you help me to fix the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you expect to see something? To get the reply from the web server you should attempt to read from the socket instead of close it immediately after send/write.

I would also suggest you to get some more confidence with network programmin.
Here you get an evergreen read:

http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would expect to see something in the index.php page, where I headed the POST request. I don't need any reply from the server.

Comment: From the way you speak I am under the impression that you expect to see something on a browser, but you won't. Your code is 'the browser' and there you should 'see' (i.e read) the result

Comment: Exactly, sorry if I was unclear. I expect to see something on the browser in the index.php page. I can't understand why I can't get the $_POST variable out of the server using the PHP on index.php page. The server, once received my request should respond with a message over http. In any case I should see the string I sent as "body" of the POST request, since I'm sure that the request is well-formed.

Comment: Maybe my understanding is bad but I expect to see the Apache server sending a response to the entity that made the request (my c++ code in this case) but at the same time keep within the POST request.

Comment: When you connect with the browser then e.g. Firefox will open a socket send a GET and display what the server replies back. That's the basic way it works. The browser won't show you the request made by your program because it's a different request. Imagine a real web site with hundreds of requests. Which one should show your text?

Comment: 'keep within' does not happen.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. How could I "pull out" that POST request for every connected clients to see ? Is there a way ?

Comment: There is no way. Unless you save the request on the server (on a database) and then build up a page that queries that database and collects all/some the POSTs. This turns your server from a sort of 'function' to something else, a collection of services, which is what normally they do.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was using this to send my data to a NodeJs server and then build up the page. Since I have some pages on Apache with PHP, instead to Reverse Proxy I had the idea to take NodeJs out of the equation and send directly the POST request to Apache. Thanks to wake me up !